# UWP Map's center not updated when moving

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, uwp-maps

I've bound the center of my `MapControl`, but the map doesn't update when I'm moving.

```
<maps:MapControl BusinessLandmarksVisible="False"
                 LandmarksVisible="False"
                 ColorScheme="Light"
                 DesiredPitch="50"
                 PedestrianFeaturesVisible="False"
                 TrafficFlowVisible="False"
                 TransitFeaturesVisible="False"
                 ZoomLevel="20"
                 RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
                 RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                 RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                 RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                 Center="{Binding CurrentGeoposition.Coordinate.Point, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 MapServiceToken="{Binding MapServiceToken, Mode=OneTime}"
                 x:Name="MapControl"/>
```

The only solution was to make it a two-way binding, but since it's bound to a `Geoposition`, I'm flooded by errors like this:

```
Error: Cannot save value from target back to source. BindingExpression: Path='CurrentGeoposition.Coordinate.Point' DataItem='MyNamespace.ViewModels.GameManagerViewModel'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl' (Name='MapControl'); target property is 'Center' (type 'Geopoint').
```

Is there a way to make this work without all the errors but *without* code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your XAML:

```
Center="{Binding MapCenter, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

And this in your viewModel:

```
public Geopoint MapCenter {
    get;
    set; }
```

If that doesn't help, can you paste your viewModel as well as your XAML?